# Referring Subjective or Argumentative questions to a personal site?

Tags: discussion, blog

Would it be wrong of me to take subjective/argumentative questions and open them for discussion on my own personal site?  I feel that it would be a perfect compromise for those of us who want to discuss stuff but understand that they are not appropriate here on Gaming.

The only problem I can see is having people advertise their blogs here by posting a subjective question and then linking to their own site, but that could be solved by only allowing referrals to particular sites owned by established Gaming users.  We would have to delete blatant advertising posts, though, but I don't see that as being as much of a problem as deleting duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, adding links to your site like that would be considered spam.

The question is still open and seeking answers (well, now it's inconveniently closed but that is beside my point). You are directing people away from the site to answer elsewhere, splitting the discussion. That is completely contrary to the primary purpose to the site, to have a canonical source for all things gaming related.

Even if the questions was deemed off topic or subjective, directing someone to your site would be considered spam and should be flagged as such. I can appreciate your enthusiasm for getting the information, but the correct thing to do is remove your outbound links.